# How to execute different statements based on the file version of a referenced dll?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# dll that references a 3rd party dll. There are different versions of the 3rd party dll.

As you might expect if the latest 3rd Party dll is present I want to use the new functionality if not I want to execute the old functionality.

I wasn't sure how to achieve this but I thought the first thing to try would be a simple if statement that decides which function to call.

So I find the assembly, get its location and hence its version info. (I need the file version as the product versions are the same).

Then a simple

```
if (version >= 3) do x() else do y()
```

When I execute the code on a machine with version 2 installed I get a `MissingMethodException` regarding `x()`. I thought I had made a stupid mistake but the logic was correct. The version is 2 so `x();` should not be executed. I decided to remove the offending method and replace it with a `throw new Exception()`. The exception is not thrown and the code completes successfully.

Here is the danger - I am thinking that this is due to branch prediction. This is dangerous because it is not an area I have any knowledge of and therefore making assumptions is a dangerous thing.

So my questions are:

Am I tacking this problem the wrong way - is there a more obvious solution that I am missing?

or

Is there a way to disable branch prediction (if that is the cause) or to somehow enforce/flag the if condition as a point that must be executed before continuing.

Here is the code being executed:

- On a machine with version 3 installed then it is fine.
- On a machine with version 2 installed I get a `MissingMethodException` regarding method `x()`.
- It I removed the call to `x();` and uncomment the throwing of the exception - no exception is thrown.

Relevant code:

```
Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(3rdPartyClass));
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);

if (fileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart >= 3)
{
    // throw new Exception("aagghh");
    x();
}
else
{
    y();
}
```

Comment: Branch prediction is a red-herring - the if test will always be conducted it's just a question of whether the processor then has the right branch of instructions loaded to execute behind it.  If not it stalls and loads the right ones.

Comment: I'd have thought that this is likely due to the fact that the call is being JIT compiled in order to do the version check (and at JIT compilation, it detects the call to the missing method). Try refactoring the actual calls into different methods or classes.

Comment: Branch prediction is about the way opcodes are loaded into a CPU instruction pipeline, they are not actually executed unless the branch condition is evaluated as predicted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection, it's possible to get a list of Methods available for a particular DLL (more specifically: Type).

You could use this methodinfo to dynamically invoke the method as specified in Vlad's solution.

In fact, you could leave out the version check and just try to find the intended method directly.

```
var methodX = assembly.GetType("sometype").GetMethod("X");
if (methodX != null)
{
    methodX.Invoke(params);
}
else
{
    assembly.GetType("sometype").GetMethod("Y").Invoke(otherParams);
}
```

Edit: This is not exactly what you want, but with this kind of reflection you can find the correct methods, also for your own assembly.

Comment: Marking as an answer as it solves the problem for me and it seems more obvious to me what is happening rather than hiding the problem by wrapping the offending function calls. The main reason being is that someone picking up the code at a later date might think the wrapping is pointless and remove it without realising the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "branch prediction": the runtime binding seems to happen as the method is executed.

So the workaround would be like this:

```
if (fileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart >= 3)
{
    CallX();
}
else
{
    CallY();
}

void CallX()
{
    DependentClass.X();
}

void CallY()
{
    DependentClass.Y();
}
```

However, anyway this seems to be a hack: you need to execute with the version of DLL you were linking against.

Comment: It does feel like a hack, that is why I wanted to ask the question to see if there was a better solution. If I have no control over what version of the dll the client has installed (and I don't want to dictate) it would then mean I would have to manage separate versions of my dll for each version of the 3rd party dll the client could have installed. Maybe that is the correct way to do it but it seems like a lot of overhead for literally two different function calls. This workaround did work for me.

Comment: @Liam: well, why don't you take all the needed versions of the dlls into the program folder? These dlls would have precedence over the client's ones. Definitely much better way to avoid DLL hell.

Comment: I honestly don't know why we don't take the required dll with us - it would seem to be the sensible thing to do. It might be a licensing/redistribution issue. This is a codebase/setup I have inherited, not that that excuses my ignorance. I will investigate further - thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a more accurate answer :

```
        Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(String));
        FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);

        ObjectHandle oh = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom("AssemblyName.dll", "namespace.class");
        object o = oh.Unwrap();
        Type to = o.GetType();

        if (fileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart >= 3)
        {
            to.InvokeMember("Method X", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, null);
        }
        else
        {
            to.InvokeMember("Method Y", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, null);
        }
```